# Casting issue in C++ Eclipse (Linux-Mint12)

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse, vector, casting

I am trying to parallelize a program (written in sequential code) to increase its performance (speedup). As a whole, the program performs image processing by zooming into images. To do so, it employs bicubic interpolation (takes into account the mean of the 16 surrounding pixels to compute a single pixel value). The following code performs said function, but I am trying to make it work with 16 pixels at a time (making it work with matrixes and vectors instead of vectors and unsigned chars), which will allow me to introduce SSE later on.

Getting back to the matter at hand, the error in my code shows up when I perform the following operation:

```
color[c]=bicubicInterpolate_paralelo(arr, auxx, auxy);
```

The operation equals the row of a 3x16 matrix (color[c]) to a 16 element vector (valorPixelCanal -> seen later in my code) returned by the function bicubicInterpolate_paralelo. It produces the following error:

> CImg-1.5.2/CImg.h:27491:46: error: cast from ‘const unsigned char*’ to
>   ‘unsigned char’ loses precision [-fpermissive]

I have tried casting in the following manner:

```
color[c] = <reinterpret_cast(const char*)>(bicubicInterpolate_paralelo(arr, auxx, auxy))
```

However, it did not solve my problem. If any of you can give me a hand with this I would sincerely appreciate it; my code is provided below, if you have any questions as to how other parts of it work I will gladly answer them. Thank you in advance!

```
void cubicInterpolate_paralelo(unsigned char p[64]/*4*/, unsigned char x[16]/*1*/, unsigned char* arr) {

        for (int ii=0; ii<16; ii++)
        {
            arr[ii] = p[1+(4*ii)] + 0.5 * x[ii] *(p[2+(4*ii)] - p[0+(4*ii)] + x[ii]*(2.0*p[0+(4*ii)] - 5.0*p[1+(4*ii)] + 4.0*p[2+(4*ii)] - p[3+(4*ii)] + x[ii]*(3.0*(p[1+(4*ii)] - p[2+(4*ii)]) + p[3+(4*ii)] - p[0+(4*ii)])));
        }
}

unsigned char* bicubicInterpolate_paralelo (unsigned char p[64][64]/*4,4*/, unsigned char x[16]/*1*/, unsigned char y[16]/*1*/) {
    unsigned char arr[64][16], valorPixelCanal[16];
    int ii, kk, jj, ss;
    int counter = 0;
    unsigned char aar[16][64];

for(ii=0; ii<64; ii++) {
    cubicInterpolate_paralelo(p[ii], y, arr[ii]);
}

for (jj=0; jj<16; jj++)
{
    for (ss=0; ss<16; ss++)
    {
        aar[jj][counter] = arr[0][ss];
        aar[jj][counter+1] = arr[1][ss];
        aar[jj][counter+2] = arr[2][ss];
        aar[jj][counter+3] = arr[3][ss];
        counter = counter + 4;
    }
}

for(kk=0; kk<16; kk++) {
    cubicInterpolate_paralelo(aar[kk], x, valorPixelCanal);
}
return valorPixelCanal;
}

CImg<unsigned char> zoom_paralelo (CImg<unsigned char> img, int zFactor) {
int i, j, k, l, c, jj;
unsigned char arr[64][64];
unsigned char color[3][16];
unsigned char auxx[16],auxy[16];

CImg<unsigned char> z_img( zFactor*(img.width()-2)-zFactor+1, zFactor*(img.height()-1)-zFactor+1, 1, 3, 0 );


#pragma omp parallel for schedule(guided, 4) num_threads(4) private(arr, c, l, k, i, j) lastprivate(color) firstprivate(zFactor) // øNecesita collapse?

for(i=0; i<z_img.width(); i++) {


    for(j=0; j<z_img.height(); j++) {
        //For R,G,B

        for(c=0; c<3; c++) { 

            for(l=0; l<64 /*4*/; l++){

                for(k=0; k<64 /*4*/; k++){

                    arr[l][k] = img(i/zFactor +l, j/zFactor +k, 0, c); // img (x,y,z,c) 
                }
            }

            for(jj=0; jj<16; jj++) 
            {
            auxx[jj] = (unsigned char)(i%zFactor)/zFactor;
            auxy[jj] = (unsigned char)(j%zFactor)/zFactor;
            }
            color[c]=bicubicInterpolate_paralelo(arr, auxx, auxy);
        }
        z_img.draw_point(i,j,color);
    }
}
return z_img;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `bicubicInterpolate_paralelo` you return a pointer to a local data array. This pointer is invalid after function return.

Then you are trying to store this pointer value (`unsigned char*`) in `unsigned char` array.

Describe how exactly this function is supposed to work so we can propose the idea how to fix it.

//EDIT:
OK, I see your problem. You wish to return the array of 16 `chars`.

It will be better to return it with output parameter:

Instead of:

```
unsigned char* bicubicInterpolate_paralelo (unsigned char p[64][64]/*4,4*/, unsigned char x[16]/*1*/, unsigned char y[16]/*1*/) {
```

you should do:

```
void/some_status bicubicInterpolate_paralelo (unsigned char p[64][64]/*4,4*/, unsigned char x[16]/*1*/, unsigned char y[16]/*1*/, unsigned char (*output)[16]) {
```

with call:

```
bicubicInterpolate_paralelo(arr, auxx, auxy, color[c]);
```

now you can write directly to `output` instead of `valorPixelCanal`

Comment: `bicubicInterpolate_paralelo` takes the 64x64 matrix p, which contains the information on the 16 surrounding pixels of 16 given pixels , and processes the 16 pixels contained in y and x. As can be seen in the function code it begins with the y axis information of the 16 pixels (y vector) and then finishes with processing the x axis information of the 16 pixels (x vector). The second loop, where arr is converted to aar, transforms our 64x16 matrix (obtained after processing x) into a 16x64 matrix; which is required to be able to employ `cubicInterpolate_paralelo`, which perfroms the operations.

Comment: I'm not sure if that answers your question, but I think I see why the error may be happening. Could it be that since I am trying to store the invalid pointer value in a predefined array, the program is trying to equal two distinct memory spaces?

Comment: Thanks!! I was thinking along the same lines but was unsure as to how the code implementation might look. I'll be able to try it out tomorrow so I'll get back to you then. Thanks again!!

Comment: I was able to implement a solution based on your advice. The final function had the following appearence: `void bicubicInterpolate_paralelo (unsigned char p[64][64], unsigned char x[16], unsigned char y[16], unsigned char* output) {` where the final assignation I used was `output = valorPixelCanal`. Thank you so much for your help!!

Comment: @PatrickFuentes Nice to hear. Now you can accept my answer :)

Comment: @PatrickFuentes your code is still wrong! Remove the valorPixelCanalCanal table and write directly to output: `cubicInterpolate_paralelo(aar[kk], x, output);`